# Intermediate Frequency in transceiver?

Tags: digital-communications, transceiver

When I learn the transmitter and receiver architecture? They have each own heterondyne architecture they use intermediate frequency to upconvert to higher frequency or downconvert to lower frequency? I have a question? What is the difference between I up or down a little bit of frequency or up or down a half of RF frequency? For example RF freq = 1GHz, I up or down to 500MHZ or seperate it to many small parts like 100Mhz, 200Mhz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of details to take into account when designing a heterodyne receiver, more than just the mathematics of the frequencies.

Generally when down converting a receiver (upconverting a transmitter), each frequency conversion is to (from) an IF in the order of 5% to 10% of the RF frequency. There are exceptions, but this is what tends to work best, most easily, cheapest etc.

If you convert to a larger fraction, then the mixing process is susceptible to low order intermodulation distortion, and the receiver specification suffers.

If you convert to a smaller fraction, then the pre-mixer filter becomes very difficult to design and build.

Comment: Thank you Neil_UK, and for Dim, I'm really sorry for my unclear question :))